# Virtual serial ports /dev/pts

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, syslinux, user-mode-linux

I'm trying to create virtual ports using `GSM cmux`. It creates virtual ports in `/dev/chn 1 2 & 3`. Which is linked to `/dev/pts 0 1 & 2`. But when I list `dev` directory there is no `pts` folder and when I try to access virtual ports it says file not found. How do I get `/dev/pts` channels? I have checked Linux kernel configuration but unable to  track down the issue.

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Thanks in advance.